# The difference between Couler and Fluer?

Tags: sens

Is there any difference between "couler" and "fluer" and derived verbs "recouler" and "refluer".

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I never heard the verb "fluer", on the other hand I'm quite familiar with the verb "affluer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Fluer vs Couler

Both verbs have the same meaning nowadays when talking about a flow of liquid but are absolutely not used in the same way.

**Fluer** (from Latin *fluere* "couler, s'écouler" → to flow).
The verb has kept the meaning it had in Latin but nowadays in French it is considered archaic and very literary and is only used as a technical word, chiefly in medicine when talking about the flow of organic fluids.

**Couler** (from Latin *colare* "filtrer, épurer" → to filter, to purify). It is the usual verb used when talking about the flow of all sorts of liquids, be it from the tap or a bottle, the course of a river, molten metal, etc.
It is used figuratively also, when talking about time.
It is used as a transitive verb to mean that you cast a piece of metal (letting the molten metal flow).

> Chaque moule fabriqué est destiné à couler une pièce unique.

### Refluer vs Recouler

Both verbs are derivative verbs formed with different meanings of the prefix re- and have different meanings.

**Refluer** comes directly from the Latin *refluere* where the prefix re- indicates a backward motion. It means to flow in the reverse direction.
It is commonly used in French when talking about the retiring tide, the course of a river or of a drain that will flow in the reverse direction.
It is used figuratively when talking about a mass of something that will move backwards. For example :

> Les CRS [ont] chargé les manifestants qui ont ensuite reflué vers la place de la République.
>
> La perte de la bataille de Waterloo fit refluer un grand nombre de prisonniers français dans les villes des Pays-Bas (Chateaubriand)

**Recouler** is formed from the French verb *couler* and prefix re- meaning “again”.
It could be used to indicate that water is once again flowing where it had stopped flowing.

> La source a longtemps été à sec mais l'eau recoule désormais.

This use is possible but I expect most French people would use "coule à nouveau" in that case.

It is used mostly to express that one will cast again a piece of metal.

Answer (score 2):

*Couler* has several meanings, one is similar to "to flow/to run" (*l'eau coule*), another common is "to sink" (*le bateau coule*.)

*Fluer* means "to flow". This verb is almost never used nowadays, however, there a many usual French words sharing the same Latin roots:

- refluer (reverse flow)
- confluent (joint flow, confluence)
- affluer / affluent / affluence (flow to the same location)
- influer / influent / influence (affect the flow)
- effluve (emanatig flow)
- fluide (that flow)
- fleuve, fluvial (a flowing river)
- fluor (originally, a liquid chemical substance)
- flot (flow)
- flotte (fleet)
- flotter (to float)
- superflu (originally, that overflow)

It is interesting to observe the English "fluent" which was obviously originally a French word is now considered an foreign word. Sometimes people say for fun "*Il est fluent en anglais*" but this is clearly considered an anglicism.

*Recouler* is rarely used and when it is, it might either mean "sink again" or "flow again."

*Refluer* means to flow in the opposite direction, like in a *reflux* (a backflow.)

Answer (score 1):

When *re-* means *again*, it's sometimes hard to know if it's a real word (*recouler*, *remanger*, *refaire* exist with *re-* meaning *again*), or just a way of speaking putting *re-* with any verb or word, in order to mean *again*:

> Rebonjour = Bonjour encore une fois = Hello again
>
> Je revais au cinéma ce soir = Je retourne* au cinéma ce soir = I go back to the cinema tonight
>
> J'ai recassé ce vase = J'ai encore cassé ce vase = I broke this vase again

*speaking about *re-* meaning *again*... it's not the case here, *retourner* doesn't mean *tourner encore* (well, it could in some context) but *to return/to go back*, in this context.

The use of *re-* in WTF new ways is a part of spoken French, sometimes just for fun and sometimes like if it was correct.

And you can even (still in spoken language) put many *re-* if you want to show the number of times: *cet été je suis rereretourné en Angleterre*, meaning it was the forth time (*retourner* = *to go again*, + 2 times *re*).

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I just want to mention that I'm not in touch with spoken French, that's why I'm always dazzled and confused how people actually talk, abbreviations, slang etc. Sometimes I feel like it's another language for me. If there is any book about differences between spoken and literary French, I'd like to read it :)